# Is there a way to overload juxtaposition in ghc?

Tags: haskell, operator-overloading, ghc

I'm trying to design an embedded language in Haskell, and, if possible, I'd like to give a custom meaning to juxtaposition, which normally denotes function application.
Or, almost equivalently, I would like to define a whitespace operator, which has a normal definable operator precedence.

Something like

```
( ) x y = x * y
```

which would then allow to write multiplication `3 * 4` as `3 4`.

Is there any way in GHC (using any extension necessary) to implement this?

Comment: That would be nice but how would you apply normal functions?

Comment: It should only be overloaded for certain types, like (in my example) two numbers.

Comment: It won't work together with type inference.

Comment: Maybe it would. I could imagine a `type family Argument` with `type instance Argument (a -> b) a`, where the term `(x::a) (y::b)` would generate the constraint `Argument a ~ b`. Surely, more code will need type annotations, but it could work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, yes!

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
module Temp where

instance Num a => Num (a -> a) where
  fromInteger n = (fromInteger n *)
  n + m = \x -> n x + m x
  -- ...
```

Then in ghci:

```
λ :l Temp
...
λ 3 (4 :: Int) :: Int
12
λ let _4 = 4 :: Int
λ 3 _4 :: Int
12
λ (3 + 4) (2 :: Int) :: Int
14
```

The symbols `0`, `1`, etc in Haskell are overloaded - `0 :: Num a => a` - they can represent anything that has a `Num` instance. So by defining a `Num` instance for functions `Num a => a -> a`, we now have the `3 :: Num a => a -> a`

Comment: `3 (4 :: Int) :: Int` is hardly a gain over `3 * 4`.

Comment: Would it be possible to make this work without explicitly casting the result to `Int` like is done in `3 _4 :: Int`?

Comment: The type annotation is needed in ghci only. In source file you could have `twelve :: Int` `twelve = 3 4`

Comment: Strictly speaking, this does not overload juxtaposition. Juxtaposition is still function application. It is quite clever though!